# FirebaseUI in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to use FirebaseUi in fragment For database listView I tried searching for anyone that has the same problem I didn't find any here is my code.

I tried referring it from another class and it didn't work like for ex
make a new class call it FirebaseDatabase and import the whole ui without any errors but when I try to make call in the fragment I get an error

```
    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    private ListView mlistView;
    public View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mlistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://kalby-3428f.firebaseio.com/");
        FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
                this,
                String.class,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                databaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            }
        };
       return   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    }

and that's the XML Code`<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kalby.kalby.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is the error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    )
```

Here "this" requires a activity, and you are using it in a Fragment, so here "this" is a Fragment not a Activity.

Try to use "getActivity()" instead of "this", you code should like:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        String.class,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        databaseReference
)
```

Try this, and based on your screen shot I think this would work.

Comment: This helped me very much thank you but I have another question I get a null pointer  final ListView  mlistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewss); even tho I have listViewss in the XML file

Comment: I had to change from view. to rootView. :D

Comment: Oh you got it? Great! I do not see your post in time :) But congratulations you solve it yourself :D